# output a loop to a log file for separate file for each value

Tags: unix, ksh

lets say I have a script like this:

```
num1 = 3
for i in $num1
  do
  echo "test $num1"
  echo "abcd"
  echo "foo"
done
```

and I want to ouput the echo to a log file for each value in num1, how would one do that? So when this runs, it should create log1.log, log2.log, and log3.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a redirection of `echo`'s output to a file:

```
num1 = 3
for i in $num1
  do
  echo "test $num1" > log$i.log
done
```

This will produce a single file called `log3` with the content `test 3`.

Maybe you want to use curly braces (ksh) to get the sequence `1 2 3` and each file to have a different content based on `i`:

```
num1=3
for i in {1..$num1}
do
  echo "$i" > log$i.log
done
```

This will produce 3 files names `log1.log`, `log2.log` and `log3.log` with the content `1` `2` and `3` respectively.

Comment: awesome! so I left one thing out, what if I have multiple echos inside the if? if I do it the same way, will they all go to that file then?

Comment: @user2061886 You can append to a file using `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: ok, so the first echo is > and then the subsequent echos are >>?